# .htaccess rewriting rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder within a site that is a seperate web app than the parent. Both are working fine, but when I go to the domain.com/folder/ path, I would like it to forward me to domain.com/folder/index.htm for consistency. This is the htaccess rule I was trying, but it wasn't working for me and I am not sure what I did wrong.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/$ folder/index.htm
RewriteRule ^folder$ folder/index.htm
```

I tried these rules at the start and end of the rule list to see if anything was overriding and nothing appears to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Mod Rewrite for this. Instead, use DirectoryIndex:

> DirectoryIndex index.htm

Place this file in the root of the folder you want this to apply to (e.g. domain.com/folder/)

Comment: I assume you mean /.htaccess has "DirectoryIndex index.php" inside it (where / is the root of your website). You need to go to the subfolder that contains your other webapp (/folder/ in your example) and create another .htaccess with "DirectoryIndex index.htm" in it.